# Angular js testing with Grunt

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, yeoman, gruntjs

I am having problem with running test in my angularjs project -When I run "grunt test" I get:

> ReferenceError: io is not defined

I am running server locally through port 3000 which is a node.js socket.io server
and implement it in index.html

```
<script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

This is the function I am testing:

```
$scope.editProject = function (dat) {
      $http({
        method: 'PUT',
        url: 'http://some.net/api/project/' + $routeParams.Id,
        data: angular.toJson(dat),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
      })
      .success(function(d) {
        var time = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'dd/MM HH:mm:ss');
        var loc = '/project/' + $routeParams.Id;
        var head = {
          User : $rootScope.UserInfo.Username,
          Message: 'Some message ',
          Name : dat.ProjectName,
          url: loc,
          date: time,
          icon : 'icon-th-list'
        };
        socket.emit('UpdateHeader', head );
        $location.url('/project/' + $routeParams.Id);
      });
    };
```

Comment: Which test runner you are using? Are you loading socket.io in your test runner?

Answer (score 2):

Install the last [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) on your project and it solve your problem. This will install [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) and [Bower](http://bower.io/) automatically. After, you can install socket.io client with bower.

```
grunt test                        # test your app
grunt server                      # preview your app
grunt                             # build the application for deployment
```

Use [Bower component](http://sindresorhus.com/bower-components/) for more package.